Twitter controversy - adjusting for population for counts of Tweets by country
There's some controversy in Ireland at the moment surrounding the number of international profiles sending tweets using a specific hashtag.
I came across some people arguing about whether or not the counts should be adjusted for population size.
This is what the raw count data look like per country.

And this is someone's population adjusted figure.

What are your thoughts on the appropriate analysis of the data. My sense is that they should not be adjusted because the interesting thing is that people in different countries are tweeting about this at all when it's an Irish story.


the interesting thing is that people in different countries are
tweeting about this at all when it's an Irish story.

If you consider the baseline participation (i.e. null hypothesis) to be 0%, sure. But that is hardly a justifiable baseline. Every story everywhere has some sort of reach outside the region it is happening in. If you want to know whether 72485 Americans talking about an Irish story is "interesting" or not, you compare it with the number of Americans talking about other Irish stories. But the other Irish stories might have happened when America had a smaller population. Whether you care about this (and hence do the adjustment) depends on why you think this whole deal might be interesting at all. For example, under the assumption that more "important" Irish stories are more likely to be talked about in America, then you need population adjustment to assess whether this particular story is more important than the baseline. On the other hand, under the assumption that each individual American that is talking about the story has a constant influence on the outcome of the story (e.g. let's imagine any American who's talking about it will influence 10 Irish people to feel a certain way towards the story, who will in turn take some actions in response to said story), then you should answer the question "How large/small is America's level of influence on this particular Irish story?" by comparing the raw number of Americans talking about the story to previous Irish stories. You can generalize this for comparison between countries.
